# Why does groupmems command ask for a password even when executed as root

Tags: root, group, privileges, cgroups

The `groupmems` command that allows us to edit group membership has a peculiar trait: When executed as root, it again asks for root password when trying to edit **any** group membership for **any** system user.

In fact it even acts for the root password pre-emptively, before it checks if such group exists (it checks if user exists before it asks for password)

If you for example execute `groupmems -g 12345 -a nobody` as root it will ask you to type in the root password anyway, before letting you know that group 12345 does not exist.

Why ( and actually how too) is it done this way for this specific command, given the omnipotence of `root` when it comes to `passwd` `/etc/sudoers` and well...everything else.

Also, this part taken straight from the `man groupmems`

> The groupmems command allows a user to administer their own group membership list without the requirement of superuser privileges. The groupmems utility is for systems that
>          configure its users to be in their own name sake primary group (i.e., guest / guest).
>
> Only the superuser, as administrator, can use groupmems to alter the memberships of other groups.

makes me wonder what would happen if I removed `root` from group `root`. Would root then possibly lose privileges to add himself back to group `root` with `groupmems`? ( I didn't want to attempt this not yet knowing how this `groupmems` command behaves

When I tried to read up on it and groups using `man` I eventually got to this interesting tidbit:

> The /etc/group file is a text file that defines the groups on the system.  There is one entry per line, with the following format:
>
> group_name:password:GID:user_list

I have personally never set a password for a `group` in linux. What would it do/accomplish/help? When would it ever be asked instead of user's password given particualar privileges ? Would then every user's password that belongs to that particular group work as the group password also?

One last thing from the `man group` and this one we can at least laugh about:

> As the 4.2BSD initgroups(3) man page says: no one seems to keep /etc/group up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "how" is via a call to `pam_authenticate`. I have no idea why, but the behavior can be eliminated by creating a file named `/etc/pam.d/groupmems` containing the following:

```
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so
```

Recompiling `groupmems` without PAM support is another way to get rid of the prompt.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never imagined I'd one day get an answer to this one, not to mention an answer that also describes how to circumvent this strange behavior (other than recompiling).